# Prevent v8::Local value from being garbage collected

Tags: c++, garbage-collection, v8

I have a function that stores the value of an argument to an `std::vector<v8::Local<v8::Value>>` property of a C++ class exposes as an ObjectWrap like this:

```
NAN_METHOD(MyObject::Write) {
  MyObject* obj = Nan::ObjectWrap::Unwrap<MyObject>(info.This());
  obj->data.push_back(info[0]);
}
```

However, when I try to read back the value *from another* C++ function, the value is lost, and becomes `undefined`.

I'm passing a number to `MyObject::Write`, and I can confirm `info[0]->IsNumber()` returns `true` before pushing it to the vector, however when reading it back, the value *it not* a number, and in fact returns `false` for all the types I tested using `Is<Type>` methods from `v8::Value`, but still returns `true` for `BooleanValue()`.

My guess is that the variable is being garbage collected after `MyObject::Write` returns, however I have no idea how to prevent this from happening.

---

I'm currently trying to initialise the value as a `Persistent` value. I tried the following attempts without success:

```
Nan::CopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value>::CopyablePersistent p;
Nan::Persistent<v8::Value> persistent(info[0]);
Nan::CopyablePersistentTraits::Copy(persistent, p);
```

And:

```
v8::Isolate *isolate = info.GetIsolate();
v8::Persistent<v8::Value, v8::CopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value>> persistent(isolate, info[0]);
```

But getting tons of C++ errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running into problems untangling this mess myself. There's a lot of template stuff going on here that we both missed. Here was the solution I found most readable:

```
// Define the copyable persistent
v8::CopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value>::CopyablePersistent p;

// Create the local value
auto val = v8::Local<v8::Value>::New(
    v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), //< Isolate required
    v8::Integer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), v) //< Isolate required
);

// Reset() is a TEMPLATE FUNCTION, you have to template it with the same
// template type parameter as the v8::Local you are passing
p.Reset<v8::Value>(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), val); //< Isolate required
```

By "info" I assume you are referring to a v8::FunctionCallbackInfo reference. If so the above code would collapse to the following:

```
void SomeFunc(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info) {
    v8::CopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value>::CopyablePersistent p;
    p.Reset<v8::Value>(info[0]);
}
```

Because the persistent is now copyable you can do things like store it inside a standard library container. This was my use case. This is an example of storing a value in a vector:

```
std::vector<v8::CopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value>::CopyablePersistent> vect;

void AccumulateData(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info) {
    v8::CopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value>::CopyablePersistent p;
    p.Reset<v8::Value>(info[0]);
    vect.push_back(p);
}
```

I hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on storing v8 values in C++, you need to make them persistent instead of local so they're independent of handle scope and not garbage-collected when the handle scope is released.

Nan [has version-independant wrappers](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/master/doc/persistent.md#persistent-references) for `v8::Persistent` and Co. Because of using inside `std::vector<>`, you'll also need to initialize `Nan::Persistent` with `Nan::CopyablePersistentTraits` so it becomes copyable (or make an own reference-counted container for it).

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I can't seem to be able to initialise `Persistent` correctly. I'm trying:

    v8::Isolate *isolate = info.GetIsolate();
    v8::Persistent<v8::Value, v8::CopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value>> persistent(isolate, info[0]);

And this:

  Nan::CopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value>::CopyablePersistent p;
  Nan::Persistent<v8::Value> persistent(info[0]);
  Nan::CopyablePersistentTraits::Copy(persistent, p);

But getting tons of errors. Do you have a code sample I could see?

Comment: Hm, SO comments don't seem to be handling code blocks correctly. I'll edit my main question with the above information for readability.

Comment: Try `Nan::CopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value>::CopyablePersistent p; p.Reset(isolate, info[0]);`

Comment: I get `error: assigning to 'v8::Object *volatile' from incompatible type 'v8::Primitive *'` (http://pastebin.com/Wdbeir34)